# Cross-platform compatible directory creation in C++

Tags: c++, cross-platform, directory

I need to dynamically create directory  based on input filenames in C++ and it must be cross-platform compatible. I am also familiar with the boost library. The input to the directory creation function will be a string with the following prototype:

`void createDirectory (std::string name)`

Sample code would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Peterchen How do I create the directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If Boost is fine, take a look at [`create_directory()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Operations-functions) from Boost.Filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Without Boost (or other cross-platform framework like Qt, wxWidgets) or some future revision of the C++ sandard, you're out of luck.

You can use [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).